# I tried making a python auto counting bot for discord but its giving me errors and not working

Tags: python, discord, chatbot

can you guys tell me what's wrong here?

[image]

here I tried removing the inits from the script but it looks like it's just not detecting the numbers

[image]

[why this is not working?](https://hashb.in/#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) <---- link is here

Comment: The error is clear for you, but not for us, because we can't see any code

Comment: Click the link I placed

Comment: It looks like your variable 'last_number' may be getting set to a string rather than a numeric value

Comment: I don't want to click your link. I want you to follow the very clear guidance about not posting screenshots of code and, instead, post a [mcve]. It's you asking _us_ for help so please follow the site guidance

Comment: i tried putting the code inside but it didn't let me do it so I just did it this way

Answer (score 0):

To start, change line 52 from:

```
(last_number + 1)
```

to:

```
((int(last_number) if last_number else 0) + 1)
```

But, again, you should not change the type of last_number between string and int. If you need both, use two different variables, and then manage them properly.

The above will most likely make the above error go away, but you will then find other errors due to the same issue.

To give a little more explanation, the `+` operator morphs according to the data types.  2 + 3 gives 5. "ab" + "cd" gives "abcd". The operands on either side of the '+' operator need to be the same type, or at least close enough that the Python interpreter can figure it out. If not, an exception will get thrown, like your code is doing. You are most likely trying to do "" + 1, which is adding a string to an integer. Thus the exception gets thrown.